# TypeError: ticker is undefined During SignalR implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm trying to implement Ticker using SignalR2 . I've tried a couple of examples including the [msdn Blog Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/15/use-signalr-sample-nuget-package-in-vs2013-preview-mvc-5-project.aspx)
I followed each step according to blog and i got the error

> TypeError: ticker is undefined

- The important thing to notice here is that It's msdn blog and in it biggest thing done is simple nuget installation . Then why i'm getting this error 
  **Detail:**
  When we installed the packet according to their instructions then in SignalR.Sample -> SignalR.StockTicker.js , after the below code

  ```
  $(function () {
  var ticker = $.connection.stockTicker, // the generated client-side hub proxy
      up = '▲',
      down = '▼',
      $stockTable = $('#stockTable'),
      $stockTableBody = $stockTable.find('tbody'),
      rowTemplate = '<tr data-symbol="{Symbol}"><td>{Symbol}</td><td>{Price}</td><td>{DayOpen}</td><td>{DayHigh}</td><td>{DayLow}</td><td><span class="dir {DirectionClass}">{Direction}</span> {Change}</td><td>{PercentChange}</td></tr>',
      $stockTicker = $('#stockTicker'),
      $stockTickerUl = $stockTicker.find('ul'),
      liTemplate = '<li data-symbol="{Symbol}"><span class="symbol">{Symbol}</span> <span class="price">{Price}</span> <span class="change"><span class="dir {DirectionClass}">{Direction}</span> {Change} ({PercentChange})</span></li>';
  ```

when I do `console.log(ticker);` I shows ***undefined*** in ***console*** while ticker is in the ready function . Any help or alternative solution will be apprecaited .

Nuget manager included the files in StockTicket.cshtml file like this

```
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="SignalR.StockTicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: when do you do `console.log(ticker);`?

Comment: after the code snippet which i posted , By the way , why did anyone gave me -1 . what is wrong in my question

Comment: you aren't showing any complete code.

Comment: Have you installed the package ? code consists of whole js file , you want that in question ?

Comment: @ImranNaqvi have you referred the library before this script but after jquery library? Could you confirm it? or if you have any error in network tab that too.

Comment: @Jai I updated my question with the file arrangement , please have a look on that again

Comment: @ImranNaqvi can you try putting console log at the doc ready closing and see if that also returns undefined.

Comment: @Jai yeah i tried that was also showing undefined

Comment: Ok, enable detailed errors in your `Startup` class when mapping `SignalR` and also enable them on the client: 

`app.mapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
{
    EnableDetailedErrors = true
});`

And on the client side, just before starting the connection:

`$.connection.hub.logging = true;`

And share the output from the console

Comment: @Matei_Radu can you give me an example

Comment: When you write `app.mapSignalR();`, instead of this you write `app.mapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true });` and on the client, just before you start the connection write `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` 
What more of an example?

Comment: @Matei_Radu oOps my bad , ok i'll check it later and mark your answer as useful if it helped even a little bit . thanks

Answer (score 1):

It maybe too late. Just make sure you have mapped your signalR in the Startup class in the root folder of your project.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
        // The rest of your configurations...
    }
}
```